# The set $\mathbb{N}_\mu$ containing sets with $\mu(E)=0$ - how to understand it?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given a measure space $(X,\mathbb{E},\mu)$, where $\mathbb{E}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ and $\mu$ is the Lesbegue measure. My professor has been writing the following (not exactly his words - what I wrote down during the lecture regarding this topic):

> Let us define $$\mathbb{N}_\mu=\{N\subseteq X\;|\;\exists E\in\mathbb{E}:N\subseteq E,\;\; \mu(E)=0\}$$
>   Let $\mathbb{E}_\mu$ be the paving [system of sets on X] such that:
>   $$\mathbb{E}_\mu=\{E\cup N|E\in\mathbb{E},N\in N_\mu\}$$

*Show that $\mathbb{E}\subseteq \mathbb{E}_\mu$* - this confused me.

How can $\mathbb{E}$ not contain the sets with length $\mu(E)=0$? Because as I understand it, the $\mathbb{N}_\mu$ is the sets of $\mathbb{E}$ with length $0$ - so if $\mathbb{E}_\mu$ is the union of $\mathbb{E}$ and all the sets in $\mathbb{E}$ with length $0$ - how can $\mathbb{E}_\mu$ be a superset to $\mathbb{E}$?

Secondly he has been writing, let $\mathbb{D}=\mathbb{E}\cup\mathbb{N}_\mu$ to show that $\mathbb{E}_\mu$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathbb{E}$ and $\mathbb{N}_\mu$ - however, as I understand it, the above  should just be $\mathbb{E}\cup\mathbb{N}_\mu=\mathbb{E}_\mu$, but this cannot be true obviously.

Any help understanding this set containing all sets with length $0$ will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How can  not contain the sets with length μ(E)=0 ? Take simply the $\sigma -$algebra of the Borel set with Lebesgue measure. There are null set that are not Borel set. In fact, if $\mathbb E$ is the Borel set of $\mathbb R$ equipped with the Lebesgue measure $m$, then $\mathbb E_m$ is the $\sigma -$algebra of Lebesgue measurable set.

Comment: @Surb So the measure space $(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{B},\mu)$ have a null set that is not Borel. As I can find, only the Cantor set satisfy this? Could you clarify what you mean a bit more (so I can understand it)?

Comment: Cantor set is definitely a Borel set (countable intersection of compact interval). I can't give a non Borel set of measure $0$ (I'm not sure we know explicitly such a set), but what is certain is that such set exist.